# gcc - frontend - submit assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, frontend

I am creating a front-end for a custom language in `gcc`.
If it is simple to manage basic arithmetic and addressing, it is not clear to me how to submit assembly commands.

How to submit assembly code to `gcc` for my language, that are architecture dependent?

Example:

```
#if ARCH=x86 || ARCH = x86_64
    pmuludq(myxmm1,myxmm2);
    paddusw(myxmm1,myxmm2);
    out(myaddress,myvalue);
#end
```

The submitted assembly will always only see instructions or I/O.

So the output should be:

```
//For out, in gas syntax:
out %register_containing_myvalue, %the_port_address
```

It is just inline assembly that I need.

Comment: Downvotes? What is the problem with this question?

Comment: I don't know either.

Comment: I'd like some clarity on your question. By *front-end* you mean you are writing a parser/compiler for a custom language which outputs C code that `gcc` can compile? And you're writing this front-end in C to be compiled by `gcc`? And then is your example an example of what you want your front-end to output, or an example of what your custom language will support?

Comment: Purely 'cos I'm interested, how come you're doing a front-end to gcc not llvm?

Comment: @lurker: my language looks a lot like C. So the code you see here is what I would like in my language.

Comment: @Joe: good question. Is it easier to do this on llvm?

Comment: I may have to vote to close this on the basis that it's a question of *what is the most elegant way...* to render something that is your own invention. So it is subjective.

Comment: @lurker: I will correct that

Comment: @Kroma GCC has a reputation for a dirtier interface between its front and rear ends, LLVM a reputation for being easier. Since I've done neither I was interested as to why you'd make the choice you had.

Comment: @Joe: got it. Actually I will have a look at it too. I would avoid to create my own compiler, even if my language is simple.

Comment: I've been involved in the development of a compiler (in this case for pilot and for cobol.)   It is not a trivial undertaking.   In general, it involves thousands of hours of concentrated effort by a large team.  Are you sure you want to do this?  In any case, the posted code is missing the actual code, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @user3629249: precisely, i want to avoid this and reuse as much as possible the existing frameworks. I will update the question to add the desired output